# How to publish free closed source application on Ubuntu Softvare Center

Tags: software-center, proprietary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)
>   [How can a free, proprietary application be submitted to the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27397/how-can-a-free-proprietary-application-be-submitted-to-the-software-center)

I want to publish application, I don't want to sell my app but also I don't want to show my source code. Am I able to publish this application on Ubuntu Softvare Center.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: the question/answer you linked deals on open source

Comment: @Takkat No, that is a general reference question. The OP's circumstances just happen to be as a FOSS dev

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards: I skipped through all answers but couldn't find anything about how to get closed source into Software Center. There was another question for non-free apps in USC with DRM not available but this is different too. That makes me believe that we should not dupe this question here easily - we'd need an answer to the canonical question on USC and closed source first. Then however they could be merged.